# Facebook Sharer.php - ignores URL QueryString

Tags: query-string, facebook-sharer

I have created a link on a site that when clicked goes here: 
http://www.keli-annpye-beshara.ca/?SMIDS=200899a1028301a28863a227638&t=THE+LIGHT+IS+OUT

When I view the source of this page I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta property="og:title" content="THE LIGHT IS OUT"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.keli-annpye-beshara.ca"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="THE LIGHT IS OUT"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="36 x 60 Acrylic on canvas SOLD"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.keli-annpye-beshara.ca/assets_d/28863/portfolio_media/lwlm_the-light-is-out---small_108.jpg"/>
```

When the page shows up on Facebook to be shared, only, canonical domain is displayed and none of the OG tags are working. When I pass the URL through facebook's litner, they say:

Admins And App ID Missing:  fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

Like Button Tag Missing:    og:title is missing. The og:title meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

Like Button Tag Missing:    og:type is missing. The og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

When I click the link to view the page as Facebook' scraper does, they see only the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.keli-annpye-beshara.ca/assets_d/28863/web_media/lm_kap-website-pic_135.jpg">
```

I can tell from this, that they are not scraping the page with the URL parameters in place. This is the default content that displays if no SMIDS parameter is passed.

Comment: The source you show at the top of your question doesn't have an <html> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Facebook will do this with any URL with query strings. Try using an URL shortener. As per the details Facebook is not grasping, I use them on a 'sharer' link ('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php'). There's many other posts that talk about this same issue here.

Comment: So sorry for the huge delay. I forgot I asked this question. You were right. We had to map our querystring to domain paths using IIS filters.